# Sending chat message with Etsy API

Tags: node.js, etsy

I have recently tried the Etsy API following [these docs](https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#section/Authentication), and I was successful in setting up app authentication, getting shop data, receipts, etc. Now my app is basically an alert bot script that listens to the API for a new receipt and sends the one who purchased the product a message automatically. Now, for the first part, it's all well, I can get the specific receipt and the user ids and all but now I am trying to figure out how to send a chat messgae to the one who purchased it. In the same docs, I do not see anything regarding a section in the API for chats.

The endpoint I use to get the receipts is:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shop_id}/receipts
```

I use nodejs to run an API call every 5 seconds using the `setInterval` method that sends this request every 5 seconds to see if there's any new receipts than the one already stored in the database, and if there are, it takes the new receipts and saves them to the database. Now, the code for all of that is way too long and I believe it is not relevant either since all I am trying to know by asking this question is how I can access the etsy chats and send messages programmatically, preferrably by using their API if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did more research about this and learned that Etsy [does not have](https://github.com/etsy/open-api/discussions/970) a chat module in their API and don't plan to any time soon.